# Converting RE code from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, regex

I have done a simple program in PHP, now need to convert this into Python:

```
$string="Google 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043 phone";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+.{10,25}[^0-9]*[0-9]{5,6}+\s/',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: When you looked at the Python re module, what did you see?  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html  Is that what you're looking for?  What specific question do you have about Python re?

Comment: If you add a use case where your regexp is used, it will be easier for us to anwser, instead, we have to decrypt it and it's no fun.

Comment: Now it works, you should "accept" an answer so people will get credit from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
for x in re.findall('[0-9]+.{10,25}[^0-9]*[0-9]{5,6}\s',STRING):print x
```

will be ok for you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, since you already did that, he would understand that. I am very new to stackoverflow actually, anyway cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you must use the "re" module to do that. Unlike in PHP, you don't need to place delimitors, so strip the "/" you have at the begining and the end of the pattern.

The Python idiom would then be :

```
import re
string="Input values"
for match in re.findall('[0-9]+.{10,25}[^0-9]*[0-9]{5,6}\s',string) : 
    print match
```

We rarely use some pretty print tools such as "print_r" in Python because most of the time, iterators and str() do the trick. So here, a simple for loop will do the job.

Comment: LOl, it's not a "textual" agreement, you must click on the "accept" bouton.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
string = "Input values"
match = re.match('/[0-9]+.{10,25}[^0-9]*[0-9]{5,6}\s/', s)
print match
```

this should be what you're looking for, if the RegEx is right.